# dynamically allocate 2d array of structs in C

Tags: arrays, c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation, calloc

(corrected the code after a few good comments pointing out some mistakes in the previous version of the code)

If I'm right, the best way to dynamically allocate a 2D array of structs in C is the following:

```
    struct xx(*array2d)[y] = malloc(sizeof(struct xx[x][y]));
```

Does it make any difference whether I store the structs in the array or store pointers to them?

I was also wondering if I may simply deallocate the allocated memory in the following way:

```
void free2d(int x, int y, struct xx array2d[x][y]) {
        free(array2d);
    }
```

Comment: Yes your thinking is correct, however the syntax you have shown have a lot of errors.

Comment: @Fredrik Can you point those errors? OPs code seems correct to me.

Comment: @David sure, the identifier 2darray is invalid, identifiers can't begin with a number. At the malloc the wrong dimension is used in the decleration, 'y' is the number of columns so it should be 'struct xx (*arr)[y]'. And in the free function, x and y needs to be parameters that come before the arr parameter.

Comment: @Fredrik good catch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The allocation code is a bit incorrect.

- variable name cannot start with a digit, thus identifier `2darray` is illegal. Use `array2d` instead
- memory allocation code look almost correct. Note that `array2d` would be a pointer to array of `x` elements of type `struct xx`. Thus the correct allocation code swap order of `x` and `y` in sizeof expression.

```
struct xx (*array2d)[x] = malloc(sizeof(struct xx[y][x]));
```

If you want `x` be the first dimensions use:

```
struct xx (*array2d)[y] = malloc(sizeof(struct xx[x][y]));
```

Personally I prefer to use the following pattern because it is less error prone:

```
struct xx (*array2d)[x] = calloc(y, sizeof *array2d);
```

2. Passing to function. It is simple, just pass array dimensions as arguments and then the array itself.

```
void foo(int x, int y, struct xx array2d[static x][y]) {
```

Note that parameter `array2d` is actually a pointer to array. The "static extent" tells the compiler that at least `x` elements pointer by the pointer are valid. It is very useful for documentation. Moreover `static` makes the declaration visually distinct from a declaration of an array.

3. Deallocation. The `free2d` function could be used if it followed the pattern from point 2. However I recommend simply using `free(array2d);`

Comment: Thank you. If I'm right, I do not have to pass x and y as parameters if they are globally defined?

Comment: @HeloKitay, No, you don't have to. It is enough that `x` and `y` are visible where `free2d` is defined. Though using a single letter names for global variables is not the best programming practice :)

Comment: Can I not get around this by passing the 2d-array to a function in this way: 
struct xx (*array2d)[]  ?

Comment: @HeloKitay does `struct xx (*array2d)[x] ` work?

Comment: Yes, it does. I'm not sure why to be honest :)

Comment: sorry I thought you wrote struct xx (*array2d)[]

Comment: So I'm wondering if it is OK to pass "struct xx (*array2d)[]" as argument, since in this way I do not have to pass x and y.

Comment: @HeloKitay, because `array2d` would be a pointer to incomplete type `struct xx[]`. As result it would not be possible to use sub-scripting `xx[i][j]` because the size of `xx[0]` would not be known

Comment: alright, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Identifiers in C cannot begin with numbers so `2darray` won't work.

Formally, the most correct way to allocated a 2D array dynamically is:

```
struct xx (*array)[x][y] = malloc(sizeof(struct xx[x][y]));
```

*However* that makes accessing the array cumbersome, because we would have to de-reference the array pointer first:

```
(*array)[i][j]
```

A common trick to avoid this is to have the array pointer not point at the "whole" 2D array, but to the first item. Which would be a `struct xx [y]` array in this case.

So we can use a pointer to the first element but still allocate the correct amount:

```
struct xx (*array)[y] = malloc(sizeof(struct xx[x][y]));
```

And now we can use this as

```
array[i][j]
```

In either of the two examples above, you free it with a single `free(array)` call.

Comment: I do not like types in `sizeof` `malloc(x * sizeof(*array));`

Comment: @0___________ I like ponies.

Answer (score 0):

I would use objects instead of types.

```
struct xx(*array2d)[cols] = malloc(rows *sizeof(*array2D));
```

To deallocate you do not need sizes only `void` pointer to your array

```
void free2d(void *array2d) {
        free(array2d);
    }
```

or simple use `free` with your pointer to the array.

Comment: "I would use objects instead of types." Why? And don't say "someone could change the code without a clue what they are doing" because that isn't much of an argument. Also one must take care not to de-reference VLA expressions because `sizeof` VLA expressions are evaluated for side effects, unlike regular `sizeof` expressions.

Comment: @Lundin it makes no difference if `x `& `y` are variables (not constant expressions)

Comment: @Lundin the topic of evaluation of sizeof for vla is very messed up. The authors of the standard likely had evaluation of the size expressions in mind but messed up the wording.there is a proposal addressing this issue. Please take a look. See http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2838.htm